# AEM JCR - Get response as JSON

Tags: json, aem, sling, jcr

We are adding some metadata under a specific location in JCR:

```
POST /some/jcr/location/_jcr_content/json HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: localhost:4502
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------554953211468377919703514
Cookie: cq-authoring-mode=TOUCH
Content-Length: 383
----------------------------554953211468377919703514
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="./value"

{ "test": "test" }
----------------------------554953211468377919703514
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=":cq_csrf_token"

ey***our csrf token***-c5Oa0
----------------------------554953211468377919703514--
```

But when we fetch this same resource, the response type is test/html`:

```
GET /some/jcr/location/jcr:content/json/value HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: localhost:4502
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: cq-authoring-mode=TOUCH

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 26 Feb 2021 13:49:38 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8 
Content-Length: 18
{ "test": "test" }
```

What configuration do we need to add in JCR, or what do we need to edit in our request to make sure that JCR returns content type `application/json`.

UPDATE: As [Sharath Madappa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3218397/sharath-madappa) replied, you can request the data in JSON format by suffixing the location with the `.json` extension. However, that results in the following format:

```json
{
    "value": "{ \"test\": \"test\" }"
}
```

While I expect it to be:

```json
{
    "test": "test"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting JSON content and then retrieving it as `Content-Type: application/json` can be done by file upload instead of adding properties.

Here is a javascript example:

```js
const data = { test: "test" };
const jsonData = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], { type: 'application/json' });
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append(`myFile.json`, jsonData, `myFile.json`);

return fetch(path, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
});
```

This example does not take in account Authn/Authz.

To fetch you data as `application/json`, you just issue a GET call to the location of the JSON file:

```
http://localhost:4502/path/to/the/folder/jcr:content/files/myFile.json
```

Answer (score 1):

use GET /some/jcr/location/jcr:content/json/value.json while making the request. Sling is able to render/return the resource in multiple formats based on the extension in the request. By default, if no extension is provided it goes with HTML. The path tells which resource, the extension, and selectors tell how and what renders the resource.

Comment: That indeed returns a json value, but in format `{ "value" : "{ \"test\", \"test\" }" }` instead of `{ "test" : "test" }`. Can I make sling return just the raw data instead of escaped values prefixed by the label?

Comment: In the form data you are saving this under a key called name. Just post a key with value test and it should work fine. The issue is with how the data is being saved rather than how sling is dealing with it.

Comment: The object `{ "test": "test" }` is just an example, we are looking at storing complex JSON objects, with multiple root level keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify the depth you want to go for besides having JSON format response.

E.g
Depth of 1(just the node) in JSON format:

```
curl -u <user>:<pass> -v <URL>/some/jcr/location/jcr:content/json/value.1.json
```

All child nodes under a certain path in JSON format:

```
curl -u <user>:<pass> -v <URL>/some/jcr/location.-1.json
```